# ReactJS render navigation based on children

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a CoreLayout component which has base layout elements:

```
1. Navigation bar
2. Components container
3. Footer
```

In navigation bar I do have a sub-navigation bar which would be displayed independantly for each compoenent - some components might have some action buttons and some won't any action buttons at all.

IndexView would have an action (link) to another page and ContactView would not display the additional navigation bar.

Router:

```
  <Route component={CoreLayout}>
    <Route path='/' component={LoginRequired}>
      <IndexRoute component={IndexView}/>
      <Route path='contact' component={ContactView}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

How do I render navigation independently for each component when navigation is located in CoreLayout component?

Should I load navigation and subnavigation for each view indivudually?
for example:

```
<Navigation><SubNavigation> list of links here </SubNavigation></Navigation>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both app-structures can work: having your navigation-bar in your CoreLayout root-component, or having a navigation-bar in each View component.

But I guess in your case you'd rather have the navigation-bar in your root-component (CoreLayout), because you want this component to define the common layout of the app. To do so, you can use the router-state (which view is currently displayed) in your CoreLayout component to decide which links to display in your navigation-bar.